# Make existing W7 ISO bootable on Mac?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, iso-image, boot-camp

Goal:

Make an image of my current Windows 7 partition (used on my forensic dell laptop) and place it on my late 2009 mac mini as a dual boot. (OSX 10.10 - Crucial 8gb ram and 250gb SSD).

I know I can download a W7.iso for a new install and use bootcamp, but I need my current setup-which is too complex to replicate in the amount of time that I have.

Is it as simple as using bootcamp and the ISO that I create in place of the new install ISO from Microsoft?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the life of me, I do not understand why so many folks still want to dual/multi boot. I find that using a hypervisor (VMWare Fusion being my personal preference) has the advantages of complete network isolation, running side-by-side within the host OS and the ability to snapshot a point in time with ease. Yes there's a performance hit but I've never needed full CPU cycles for my own use cases.

Additionally, Fusion (as I'm sure the competition does) allows direct, over-the-wire cloning of a running Windows PC that is then imported as a virtual machine. I did this a couple of years ago with much success and not much difficulty. This might be a good solution for you. You can find more info [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/windows_to_mac).

Comment: If it was going to be forensics only, i wouldn't mind the performance hit so much.  I'm use to waiting and it can't be any slower than using the targets computer, imaging etc...

Secondary use will be for windows based gaming- bf4 primarily.  My son wants to play beam or beaming drive?

Requirements are stout on both and need all the Mac mini can deliver.

Thanks for the links, if I can't find a way to take my existing windows image and dual boot it, this will be my go to.  Appreciated.

Comment: @user359052, glad I was able to help. The question of dual/triple boot comes up often so I feel like a broken record but I guess not everyone thinks of virtualization at first.